# R survey svymean returns 0 with no data

Tags: r, survey

Why does the survey package in R return a mean value of 0 when calculating the mean of no data? Shouldn't the result be NA?

Example:

```
survey::svymean(
   ~x, 
   design = survey::svydesign(
      ids = ~1, 
      weights = ~w, 
      data = data.frame(
         x = rep(NA_real_, 100),
         w = rep(1,100)
      )
   ), 
   na.rm = TRUE
)
```

returns:
   `mean SE`
`x    0  0`

Without the `na.rm=TRUE`, the function returns NA:

```
survey::svymean(
   ~x, 
   design = survey::svydesign(
      ids = ~1, 
      weights = ~w, 
      data = data.frame(
         x = rep(NA_real_, 100),
         w = rep(1,100)
      )
   )
)
```

returns:
   `mean  SE`
`x   NA NaN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's what the code happens to return in this case and it wasn't thought to be worth adding a special case for the combination of no non-missing data and `na.rm=TRUE`

Comment: for anyone running across this in the future, Thomas Lumley is the author of the R survey package.